# What are ideals in a complete lattice?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

If I have a complete lattice $L$, what conditions do I need for $I\subseteq L$ to be an ideal?

In a general lattice the conditions are:

- $I$ is a lower set;
- $I$ is closed under (finite) joins.

For a complete lattice, do we require that $I$ be closed under arbitrary joins? Or is there a special name for such a "better" ideal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer [here](http://books.google.pl/books?id=0oet6aH_7Q0C&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=%22ideal+in+a+complete+lattice%22&source=bl&ots=ApXAty_ZsU&sig=JbJ_iZ2Vj8w51voxYmGLAR2nQ3E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Aa8dUYv5Bsfeswasy4HwDA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22ideal%20in%20a%20complete%20lattice%22&f=false). Such a "better" ideal is called a *complete ideal*.